# Получение IP адреса из беззнакового числа

Tags: ip

Изучаю Rakudo (бывший Perl6), конвертирую IP в беззнаковое целочисленное значение:

```perl
say :256['151.101.129.69'.comb(/\d+/)]
```

Получаю на выходе 2540011845. Как это число преобразовать снова в IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, проще сделать это через `map`.

```
say join ".", map {((2540011845+>(8*$_))+&0xff)}, (3...0)
```